# Embedding large portions of CSS and JS into <head> without links

Tags: javascript, html, css

So... Just so you have less reasons to call me an idiot, here's why I need this:
I'm currently working on an offline project that uses jruby. So, to generate reports on the fly, it was decided (by my superiors) to use JavaFX's WebView component - so, HTML, CSS and JS.

But here's the catch: no using file system. All the content is drawn from DB and generated on the fly. No internet either. So all the content to be loaded into the WebView is to be in a single file, however enormous.

I have an HTML page and two huge files - one js, one css. When I use `<link>` tag for css and `<script src="...">` for js - all works. Both in a browser and if I artificially load the page into a WebView. But if should I copy-paste the files into corresponding `<style>` and `<script>` tags (as it, probably, will be handled in the program), half the things do not work. Is there a special way for doing it right?

Here are the html, css and JS I'm working with (html is filled with sample data so it can be seen if everything works):

[html file](http://www.2shared.com/document/krZvSBM6/index.html)[css file](http://www.2shared.com/document/vts4CdV2/total.html)[javascript file](http://www.2shared.com/document/dxqZ9Y9U/total.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could try and merge them. Read more about this [here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/combine-minify-javascript-php/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Sadly, merging didn't help. Here's what did, though: being put into <head> contents of .js files had to be uncompressed versions and to be put into separate <script> tags. Then, it works. 20000 javascript lines are too much for a single tag, it seems.